# How would I count the number of coloured cells in an Excel worksheet ?

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have a number of worksheets in my Excel file and if some cells on the worksheets are not filled they get filled in '`Red`'.

What I want is on its own page, say I call it '`Cells that aren't filled` Worksheet', I want each worksheet name on the left hand side, with the number of cells filled '`Red`' next to it so users know what's left to be filled and on what page.

I'm a total newbie at Excel in that I haven't used it since high school. Is there a simple line of code I can apply to a cell to count the number of certain coloured cells on that worksheet ? I have look online, and there's talks of using VB, I've never used that so I'm just wondering if there's an easier way :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, good to know anyway, suppose I'll have to learn abit of VB, thanks

Comment: You can't count colored cells, but you can count blank cells in a given range.  If you know the range of cells beforehand that are in question, then you would just have to add the worksheet names yourself.  A simple use of COUNTIF will find blank cells: `COUNTIF(range, "=")`

Comment: ahh cool, i could do that but some mandatory columns are inbetween optional columns which would mean me writing it out for each column rather than the whole sheet at once :( Its okay, i've found a simple script i can use hopefully isn't to difficult to implement. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: @pnuts, even easier.  Wasn't aware that function existed.

Comment: @pnuts, for what it's worth, the two functions handle the cell with a single apostrophe differently.  COUNTBLANK appears to count `='` as a blank, whereas COUNTIF does not consider that blank since the cell technically has something in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only really count cells by color using some VB such as:

```
Function CountColorIf(rSample As Range, rArea As Range) As Long
Dim rAreaCell As Range
Dim lMatchColor As Long
Dim lCounter As Long

lMatchColor = rSample.Interior.Color
For Each rAreaCell In rArea
    If rAreaCell.Interior.Color = lMatchColor Then
        lCounter = lCounter + 1
    End If
Next rAreaCell
CountColorIf = lCounter
```

And then a formula such as:

```
=CountColorIf(N9,F5:F9)
```

With N9 being a cell to reference your color against and F5:F9 being the range of cells to check.

I think trying to find a way without VB is going to be more complicated then with...

Comment: Heyman cheers for the input.I managed to do this before you answered. Heres my other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519030/counting-coloured-cells-doesnt-work-with-conditional-formatting-in-excel?noredirect=1#comment47193219_29519030. it doesnt work when testing conditional formatted cells :(